# Display MYSQL query result in horizontal view

Tags: php, mysql

We have employee attendance system in mysql database but it dont have the reporting capability, i am trying to generate reports using PHP.

Let me explain clearly :

employee punch in and punch out daily. These punch ins and outs are stored in mysql database table ( attendance). This table contain 5 fields like punch in, punchout, employeeid, note, attendanceid. Our employee names and other details are stored in other table ( employee).

My query is that I want to generate a report using these two tables in horizontal view.

example :

column1 : employee name
column2  : punchin
column3 : punchout
column4 : punchin
column  : punchout

I am able to generate daily report for all employees but looking to generate weekly/monthly report.

pls help.

thanks,
raj

Comment: You might know what you're asking for - but I don't think you've explained it very well. Please provide relevant schema details, sample records and an example of how you want the data formatted.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to do a pivot query (switch rows and columns).  MySQL has no support for this, but it can be simulated.  It is much easier to just get the data you need and parse it with php, however.

It sounds like (and this is just a guess) you want the employee to be the first column and all punch ins/outs to be in the same row for that employee.

Here's a crack at what you want to do:

```
$data = select_all_relevant_data_with_mysql();
$employees = array();
while ($row = $data->fetch()) {
   $employees[$row['employee']][] = array(
      'in' => $row['punchin']
      , 'out' => $row['punchout']
   );
}
```

(Note this will generate undefined index notices for each Employee entry.  You should handle this, but it would double the code there).

Now you have the punchin/out data arranged per employee (hopefully in order, MySQL can handle that easily with ORDER BY).

Now you do something link:

```
foreach ($employees as $name => $punches) {
   echo <<<HTML
      <tr><td>$name</td>
HTML;
   foreach ($punches as $punch) {
      echo <<<HTML
         <td>$punch[in]</td><td>$punch[out]</td>
HTML;
   }
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

I would suggest using a templating system like [PHPTAL](http://phptal.org/) for this kind of thing.  Shameless plug :)

Answer (score 0):

The report format is too vague. 
Should it be:

- one row per user followed by all punchins and punchouts as a single row (not nice).

or

- should the punchins/outs be aggregated to give a grand total of worked time per user over the period?